# Is the export command behaviour different in sh and in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script without the first line that specifies which shell type to use to interpret commands.

This .sh file has been used on a SCO Unix 5 system until the moment of migration on a more modern system like RHEL 7.

It seems to me that sh is the default shell in SCO Unix while the bash is the default shell in Red Hat Linux, so I think that porting the script to linux and running it, this one will be interpreted by default with the bash.

Coming to the point, in this script there is a section like this:

```
MY_SETUP=1
echo $MY_SETUP
MY_SETUP=2 export MYSETUP
echo $MY_SETUP
```

As you can see the name of the variable after the export command is not the one in the assignment (it was a typing mistake).

I noticed that the value of MY_SETUP variable after this section is different if the script is interpreted by sh or bash.

- sh MY_SETUP value = 2
- bash MY_SETUP value = 1

It seems that bash completely ignores the assignment inline with the export command and keeps the previous value.

All this run without returning any error, so I was wondering why there is a different behavior. Can someone explain me?

**EDIT:**

From Stéphane Chazelas answer it seems that in bash this instruction

```
var=x export var
```

doesn't set the "x"value and doesn't export it, but in my environment it does both. I'm confused.

Comment: You're right about your edit, looks like I messed up my tests, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you detected a POSIX deviation in `bash` that is also a deviation from the historic Bourne Shell. You may call it a bug or a just deviating behavior.

The script you refer to prints

```
1
2
```

with all shells except bash in default behavior.

If you call `bash --posix`, it works correctly.

From a pointer from user Kusalananda it seems that bash by default makes all builtin commands restore their temporary environment at exit and not just for the non-special builtins. Since `export` is a special builtin, POSIX requires a shell to behave the same as a Bourne Shell from the early 1980s end to keep the environment value.

Since bash does not implement this by default, you get the deviation.

Comment: `bash` in its POSIX mode does the right thing though.

Comment: Point 30 in [Chet's list of differences](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/POSIX) between `bash`'s default mode of operation and `bash --posix` may be relevant, possibly.

Comment: It would be a bug if it didn't work as documented. Here `bash` behaves as required by POSIX when in POSIX mode, like when called as `sh`, and works as documented (and some would argue in a less surprising way) otherwise.

Comment: Note that `zsh` behaves like `bash` here, so it's not _all shells except bash_.

Comment: I tested `zsh`, so it may be that zsh changed behavior between different releases.

Comment: The Z shell needs POSIX mode turned on, too.  `setopt POSIX_BUILTINS`.

Comment: Not for zsh version 4.3.4

Comment: I used the present not the past tense.  (-:

Comment: Since zsh is far from a POSIX shell (even on POSIX mode), I am not looking for a new version every day ;-)

Comment: Bash acts exactly the same as `Bourne` shell with `export`. No difference to report.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the behavior is different. The whole description is not so simple.

#### First: when is it equal?

This code line :

```
$ var=1; printf "%s" "$var"; var=2 export var; echo " $var"
```

Will print `1 2` in all (non-csh like) shells **except** zsh.

```
jsh             : 1 2      # ATT version sh (heirloom).
ash             : 1 2
yash            : 1 2
dash            : 1 2
zsh/sh          : 1 2
bash            : 1 2
posixbash       : 1 2
lksh            : 1 2
mksh            : 1 2
ksh93           : 1 2
attsh           : 1 2
zsh             : 1 1
```

That looks like a mistake of zsh to me. How could be reasonable that exporting a variable does not retain the exported value ?

But that is because the exported variable: `var`, is the same var that is printed.

#### Exporting some other var.

If the line is changed to something more similar to what you are asking, with some other varname, like this:

```
$ var=1; printf "%s" "$var"; var=2 export othervar; echo " $var"
```

The difference(s) become clear:

```
jsh             : 1 2
dash            : 1 2
bash            : 1 1
posixbash       : 1 2
ksh93           : 1 2
zsh             : 1 1
```

It is clear that bash is different to old sh (Bourne), newer sh (dash), ksh and others (not listed here).

But what is more important is that bash acts differently than `bash --posix`.

#### Posix requirement.

Some of the shell builtins (not all) are called "special built-ins":

From: [2.14. Special Built-In Utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14)

> The following "special built-in" utilities shall be supported in the shell command language.
>   … however, the special built-in utilities described here differ from regular built-in utilities in two respects:
>
> 1. An error in a special built-in utility may cause a shell executing that utility to abort, while an error in a regular built-in utility shall not cause a shell executing that utility to abort. …
> 2. As described in Simple Commands, variable assignments preceding the invocation of a special built-in utility remain in effect after the built-in completes; this shall not be the case with a regular built-in or other utility.

So, in a simple command: `var=2 specialBuiltin` the variable `var` should retain its value after the specialBuiltin has exited. But not all shell implementations follow such rule.

So, this should print `1 hello 2` (as `eval` is an special builtin):

```
var=1; printf '%s ' "$var"; var=2 eval printf %s hello; echo " $var"
```

It does in `sh` and `bash --posix` but not in plain bash.

#### List of special builtins.

In fact, The [POSIX list of special builtins is here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/sbi.html), the list being:

```
02 break
03 :
04 .
05 continue
06 eval
07 exec
08 exit
09 export
10 readonly
11 return
12 set
13 shift
14 times
15 trap
16 unset
```

The number in first column is the value of var used for each test.

We could test all special builtins (except exit, exec and times) with this code:

```
var=01;
while : ; do var=02 break; done;    printf ' %s' "02-$var"; var=01
var=03 : ;      printf ' %s' "03-$var"; var=01
echo 'printf " %s" "04-<$var>"' >source-sh
var=04 . source-sh; printf ' %s' "04-$var"; var=01
c=0; while ((c++<1)); do
     var=05 continue
     done; printf ' %s' "05-$var"; var=01
var=06 eval 'printf " %s" "06-<$var>"'; printf ' %s' "06-$var"; var=01
#( var=07 exec bash -c  'printf " %s" "07-$var"'); var=01
#( var=08 exit;     printf ' %s' "08-$var" ); var=01 
var=09 export var;  printf ' %s' "09-$var"; var=01
var=10 readonly i;  printf ' %s' "10-$var"; var=01
varfun(){ var=11 return; }; varfun; printf ' %s' "11-$var"; var=01
var=12 set -- aa ;  printf ' %s' "12-$var"; var=01
var=13 shift;       printf ' %s' "13-$var"; var=01
var=15 trap;        printf ' %s' "14-$var"; var=01
var=16 unset j;     printf ' %s' "15-$var"; var=01
echo
```

To print this list:

```
jsh             :  02-02 03-03 04-<04> 04-04 05-05 06-<06> 06-06 09-09 10-10 11-11 12-12 13-13 15-15 16-16
dash            :  02-02 03-03 04-<04> 04-04 05-05 06-<06> 06-06 09-09 10-10 11-11 12-12 13-13 15-15 16-16
bash            :  02-01 03-01 04-<04> 04-01 05-01 06-<06> 06-01 09-09 10-01 11-01 12-01 13-01 15-01 16-01
posixbash       :  02-02 03-03 04-<04> 04-04 05-05 06-<06> 06-06 09-09 10-10 11-11 12-12 13-13 15-15 16-16
ksh93           :  02-02 03-03 04-<04> 04-04 05-05 06-<06> 06-06 09-09 10-10 11-11 12-12 13-13 15-15 16-16
zsh             :  02-01 03-01 04-<04> 04-01 05-01 06-<06> 06-01 09-01 10-01 11-01 12-01 13-01 15-01 16-01
```

As you can see, where posix request that var retain `02` most shells retain it and print `02-02`, but not in bash (nor zsh) as they print `02-01`. Only in `export` is bash printing `09-09` and zsh printing `09-01`.

Comment: So you're saying that in my case bash doesn't keep the value assigned because, since the "export var" command used individually makes a variable visible in the subprocesses and since the bash with the default behavior doesn't take into account special builtins, my bash takes care of exporting the name of the variable that doesn't match with the one assigned, losing the value?

Comment: Please do not claim to have a complete list of Bourne-alike shells if you miss important implementations. For an expressive comparison, it is sufficient to list the ones that are most important and/or well maintained. These are: **bash dash bosh mksh ksh88 ksh93 zsh** I am not sure wether **yash** should be in that list because of many deviations. **zsh** also has many deviations and **dash** cannot be used on a full blown UNIX system since it misses support for multi-byte characters.

Comment: Let me add a note to the heirloom shell. It has been derived from the SunOS Bourne Shell and modified in various undocumented ways. It is not portable and it is unmaintained. In fact, there was no more than 3 months of work from the maintainer. If you like to verify the behavior of the SunOS Bourne Shell, it is better to use the "osh" binary compiled from the bosh sources, since that is very close to the SunOS original and portable.

Comment: @alessaro "Your case" is not the `export var` case. In the later case, the first I cover, both `sh` and `bash` act exactly the same. "Your case" is the second I cover.

Comment: @schily I am very (very) sorry for your pain. ... But the only thing that matters here is wether "the Bourne shell" prints `1 1` or `1 2`, the rest are just opinions.

Comment: If this is all you like to tell, why then do you wrote so many opinions?

Comment: @schily Where is the opinion in reporting what a list of shells actually do? Try yourself, the code is in the answer, just copy it !.

Comment: I am sorry, you did start to mention that you have an opinion to publish. Could you explain that and explain why you claim that you used a complete set of shells even though you used a subset?

Comment: @schily That your opinion is only that you dislike the list of shells is clear and has already been recorded. Anything useful to submit?